# Trouble running python unit tests with tox - ImportError for module that is already installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, tox, matrix-synapse

I am new to python and am trying to run unit tests for this project:
https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse

I am running tox from the top level of the project.  I get this error:
exceptions.ImportError: No module named pymacaroons

But pymacaroons is already installed using pip. To my knowledge, I only have one version of python.  Really stumped here.

Comment: can you provide the output of `pip list | grep -i "macaroon"`?

Comment: Sure. pymacaroons (0.12.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tox` creates its own virtual environments and installs dependencies according to `tox.ini`. `pymacaroons` is not listed in `tox.ini` hence it's not installed. To install it either add `pymacaroons` to `tox.ini` (section `[testenv]`, key `deps`) or add `-rrequirements.txt` to `tox.ini` and list `pymacaroons` in the `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `-rrequirements.txt` in your `tox.ini` and list `pymacaroons` in `requirements.txt` and you're still having issues it's likely that tox is not updating, removing the folder `.tox` will force tox to update